# Cannot call Google Apps Script doPost() method from Twilio number

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

Trying to receive an SMS at my Twilio number and send a POST request to a Google Apps Script app URL as a result of the received SMS.

I have this doPost() message:

```
function doPost(request) {

    return ContentService.createTextOutput("User says: "+JSON.stringify(request));
}
```

Some text should be spit out containing the request data.

My doPost() method never gets called.  I can't tell if the POST request is actually being sent by Twilio.  I see in the Twilio number message log that my SMS is received by Twilio.  But after that I can't tell.  I have the Twilio number configured for webhook - HTTP POST, and the published URL of my Google Apps Script project.  If I change that to HTTP GET my doGet() method DOES get called.  I need to doPost() method called, though.  any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following confirmation?

#### Confirmation points :

- Redeploy Web Apps as a new version again.

  - When the script is updated, Web Apps is required to be redeployed as a new version for reflecting the update.
- Confirm setting for Web Apps.

  - "Execute the app as:" is "Me".
  - "Who has access to the app:" is "Anyone, even anonymous".
- Retrieve a log of `request` using Stackdriver.

  - The sample script is as follows. Please copy and paste it. And redeploy Web Apps.
  - Request POST.
  - On script editor, click View -> Stackdriver Logging
  - By this, when POST request is received, you can see the log.

#### Sample script :

```
function doPost(request) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request)); // Here
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("User says: "+JSON.stringify(request));
}
```

By above confirmation, the reason of your problem may be found. But if this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I decided to not use doPost() at all, and just use doGet().  Now in doGet() I look at the incoming request and make a decision about whether the request is the standard one to return the web page content, or whether the request is from Twilio, and return that data appropriately.  This solved my problem because after working on it for a long time I still could not get doPost() to work.  I used a very similar script to examine the request to seethe differences so that I could decide how to differentiate the two request types.

Comment: @jeff Thank you for your additional information. In this case, I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just use doGet().  See my response to the previous comment.